# How to connect mysql with Basex?

Tags: mysql, basex

I have a application with Mysql as Database which is using a lot XML/HTML.
I would like to process mysql data in BaseX and update database through it. Is there any simple way to connect Database? 
I checked http://docs.basex.org/wiki/SQL but it is not working. Can you please give me simple example what I have to do to connect? 
I got error  *An SQL exception occurred: 'No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test'*
here is my code:

```
let $conn := sql:connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test")
return sql:execute($conn, "SELECT * FROM coffees WHERE price < 10")
```

Where should I put mysql jdbc connector (mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar) in basex to make it work?
Thanks

Comment: This question is not a good fit for SO as we don't give examples. It is more appropriate on our mailing list and has been asked just a couple of days ago, see https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/pipermail/basex-talk/2014-November/007690.html for some more information (so, to make it short: put it into lib/).

Comment: thanks for comment, why there is error like " Could not initialize supplied driver: 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"? I already put my jdbc driver in lib directory

Comment: Did you restart BaseX? jars are only loaded during startup

Comment: I am using GUI. so I closed it and reopened it.

Comment: I think it,s working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First download latest version of mysql jdbc driver. Here is [5.1.36](http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.tar.gz), inside this, there is .jar file, extract jar file and put in BaseX installation folder's lib directory. In windows it is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\BaseX\lib
```

Restart the server or GUI. for GUI you should close everything, better to open from bin directory's **basexgui**

```
sql:init("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"),
let $con := sql:connect('jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASSWORD')
return sql:execute($con, "select version()")
```

for detail queries [BaseX documentation](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/SQL)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In Ubuntu, as of version 7.9 of BaseX you need to modify the shell script that runs BaseX (sudo vi /usr/bin/basex) to load the JDBC driver adding the line find_jars /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar 2>/dev/null  , becuase in Linux there is no "lib" folder for Basex (https://www.mail-archive.com/basex-talk@mailman.uni-konstanz.de/msg04708.html). Please modify your answer adding that detail. It worked for me only on that way.